# Select Insert in oracle performance issue

Tags: sql, oracle

I am performing data migration in SQL Query using simple select insert approach

I am not getting the reason for performance differences for 2 queries mentioned below performing same task on same data set.

I was using the query below, which is taking infinite(job was killed after 72 hours) duration to complete, with no indexes on SELECT tables

```
INSERT INTO X (A,B,C,D,E,F,G)
 SELECT 'ORSTX',
      'ORGX_LVL_1',
      CONCAT ('NC_CAT_GL_COM_VAL_', MAP.AUTO_ID),
      CONCAT ('CAT_GL_SCOPE_', MAP.AUTO_ID),
      MAP.SYSTEM,
      REF.COMPANY_CODE,
      1
 FROM TEMP_CAT_GL_BU MAP
         JOIN TEMP_CAT_GL REF ON MAP.CODE  = REF.CODE
 WHERE MAP.SYSTEM = 'ABCD'
      AND REF.SYSTEM = 'ABCD';
```

while the query below is completed in finite (acceptable) time

```
 INSERT INTO X (A,B,C,D,E,F,G)
   SELECT A,B,C,D,E,F,G FROM (SELECT 'ORSTX',
      'ORGX_LVL_1' AS A,
      CONCAT ('NC_CAT_GL_COM_VAL_', MAP.AUTO_ID) AS B,
      CONCAT ('CAT_GL_SCOPE_', MAP.AUTO_ID)AS C,
      MAP.SYSTEM AS D,
      REF.COMPANY_CODE AS E,
      1 AS F,
      MAP.AUTO_ID AS G
   FROM TEMP_CAT_GL_BU MAP
         JOIN TEMP_CAT_GL REF ON MAP.CODE  = REF.CODE
   WHERE MAP.SYSTEM = 'ABCD'
      AND REF.SYSTEM = 'ABCD'
   ORDER BY MAP.AUTO_ID);
```

Comment: What are the indices on the tables?  What does `EXPLAIN` show you?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen EXPLAIN goes infinite too for the 1st query, while 2nd query shows table access full as i already mentioned there are no indexes

Comment: @Aleksej i added order by to use rownum and insert in batches, although i observed that performance improvement was merely due to order by so i eliminated rownum

Comment: What is thee explain plan for the second query, also how exactly are you doing explain plan?

Comment: @vishad i am using SQL developer for explain plan

Comment: Few questions: (1) what are the size of the tables (number of relevant records), (2) when you say _acceptable_ time, what do you mean? (3) Did you try running the `SELECT`s alone? If yes, what was the response time? I'm asking this because I would first attempt to see WHERE the bottleneck is (SELECT or INSERT).

Comment: @FDavidov bottleneck is INSERT , select query is executed within a few minutes for both the cases

Comment: @AndroidMason: If you are using SQLdeveloper, then select would have returned first 50 rows by default, whereas insert would only get completed once all the rows have been inserted. So when you say, select got completed then was it the time for getting 50 rows or did you scroll down the complete set

Comment: Why do they even insert different values into the X table for A,B, ... ? Are there perhaps triggers on the X table with some rules that could be slower depending on the value? Like for example an update on another table?

Comment: @vishad scrolled down complete set

Comment: @AndroidMason, you answered only one question. Also, please edit your question and add the CREATE TABLE script for `X`.

Comment: Did you run one query, then run the other in another session without committing or rolling back the first? If so then the second one to be executed may be blocked by the presence of unique or PK constraints and matching data in the first.

Comment: I second @DavidAldridge 's thought - this sounds very much like a problem with locking, rather than a problem with the query itself.

Comment: Just to make sure - you were talking about migration, are the tables involved in your INSERT statements are all from same Oracle database or are we talking here about multiple systems (maybe not even Oracle)?

Comment: @DavidAldridge i had rollbacked all transactions before executing the query. I observed that CPU utilization rises to almost 99 % on my DB server when the first query is executed(which never completes). i guess concat operations might be culprit in select might be the culprit.

Comment: @AndroidMason , if you replace the CONCAT function with || (concat operator), can you get the execution plan?

Comment: @AndroidMason, can you share the DDL (tables + other data structures if exist)?